# How can I call an element from list based on another variable's value?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variables

I'm following along an online program to self-teach myself programming and the problem I'm facing involves using the value of a variable (in this case `current_room`) to access the first element, from an established list (in this case `room_list`.)

How can an element from a list(`room_list`) be accessed based on the value (that will change) of a variable(`current_room`) outside the list?

I managed to force my code to work by setting individual outputs for `room_list` based on the value of `current_room`, however I feel there is more concise way of achieving my desired result.

**Code:**

```
print("Welcome to Dungeon Escape!\n")

#Room List (17 Rooms in total)
room_list = []
#0
room = ['''You are in Your Cell.
The door to the East is open.\n''', None,1,None,None]
room_list.append(room)
#1
room = ['''You are in a Hallway.
The Hallway extends North and South.
A Door is to the East.
Your Cell is to the West\n''',2,6,4,0]
room_list.append(room)
#2
room = ['''You walked to the North end of the Hallway.
A Cell door is to the West.
The Hallway extends South.\n''',None,None,31,1]
room_list.append(room)
#3
room = ['''You entered the Cell.
A rotting corpse is chained to the wall.
The Cell door is to the East.\n''',None,2,None,None]
room_list.append(room)
#4
room = ['''You walked to the South end of the Hallway.
A Cell door is to the West.
The Hallway extends North.\n''',1,None,None,5]
room_list.append(room)
#5
room = ['''You entered the Cell.
Rats scurry into the walls.
The Cell door is to the East.\n''',None,4,None,None]
room_list.append(room)
#6
room = ['''You are in a long passage.
Torches light the way ahead.
Doors lead North, South, and East.\n''',7,None,9,1]
room_list.append(room)
#7
room = ['''You entered the Guard's Office.
There are signs of a struggle.
Doors lead to the South and West.\n''',None,None,6,8]
room_list.append(room)
#8
room = ['''You force your way into the Armory.
No supplies remain inside.
The door is to the East.\n''',None,7,None,None]
room_list.append(room)
#9
room = ['''You entered the stairwell.
A long flight of stairs is before you.
Proceed South to climb up or North to climb down.\n''',6,None,10,None]
room_list.append(room)
#10
room = ['''The Throne Room is atop the stairs.
Rotting food from a great feast fills your nostrils.
There are paths to the North and South.\n''',9,None,11,None]
room_list.append(room)
#11
room = ['''You are in the kitchen.
A fire has not been lit here in a while.
Doors lead to the North and West.\n''',10,None,None,12]
room_list.append(room)
#12
room = ['''You walk into the pantry.
It appears to be ransacked.
Doors lead East and South.\n''',None,11,13,None]
room_list.append(room)
#13
room = ['''You step into the Courtyard.
Finally there is fresh air.
Paths lead to North, East, South, and West.\n''',12,14,15,16]
room_list.append(room)
#14
room = ['''You take the path East.
The wall at the end is too tall to climb.
The return path leads West.\n''',None,None,None,13]
room_list.append(room)
#15
room = ['''You take the path South.
The Gate is blocked by burning debris.
The return path leads North.\n''',13,None,None,None]
room_list.append(room)
#16
room = ['''You take the path West.
A break in the wall leads further West.
The return path leads East.\n''',None,13,None,17]
room_list.append(room)
#17
room = ['''You escape throught he break in the wall.
Congratulations you are free!
Thanks for playing Dungeon Escape!\n''',None,None,None,None]
room_list.append(room)

#Variables
current_room = 0
done = False

while not done:
    if current_room == 0:
        print room_list[0][0]
    elif current_room == 1:
        print room_list[1][0]
    elif current_room == 2:
        print room_list[2][0]
    elif current_room == 3:
        print room_list[3][0]
    elif current_room == 4:
        print room_list[4][0]
    elif current_room == 5:
        print room_list[5][0]
    elif current_room == 6:
        print room_list[6][0]
    elif current_room == 7:
        print room_list[7][0]
    #elif statements continue up to 17
    else:
        done = True
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty to shorten your question quite a bit since it will be easier to read/understand if you come straight to the point. Also, you should always add the main language tag, in your case `python`.

Comment: Also, if your code already works and you want some input on possbile improvements, there's also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you look closly on your code

```
...
if current_room == 0:
    print room_list[0][0]
elif current_room == 1:
    print room_list[1][0]
elif current_room == 2:
    print room_list[2][0]
...
```

you should see a pattern here:

The index you use to get sublist from `room_list` is always the same as `current_room`, so you can simply use

```
...
print room_list[current_room][0]
...
```

Of course you have to add bounds checking (e.g. what happens if `current_room >= len(room_list)`?), but that's left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is that one from sloth, but I want to suggest that you could benefit from using a class named Room with a public print_room() method and a get_index() method, so you could do:

```
room = Room('''You are in Your Cell.The door to the East is open.\n''', None,1,None,None)
room_list.append(room)

room = Room('''You are in a Hallway.The Hallway extends North and South.A Door is to the East.Your Cell is to the West\n''',2,6,4,0)
room_list.append(room)

# ... keeps up until 17 rooms...

current_room = 0 # or whatever

# This now remains 3 lines
for room in room_list:
    if current_room == room.get_index():
        room.print_room()
```

Much more compact code and legible too. It woud be great also if you load everything from a file. One room per line.

Just a suggestion